# Execute some JSF business logic before POST to external URL

Tags: java, jsf, url, post, jsf-2

I have the following form on my JSF page which posts to an external credit card processor.
I would like to use a JSF action method instead so I can write some business logic. How do I do the post from an action method and include the fields below?

```
        <form action="#{checkoutBean.sagepayURL}" method="post"
            id="SagePayForm" name="SagePayForm">

            <input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol"
                value="#{checkoutBean.sagepayMessage.vpsProtocol}" /> <input
                type="hidden" name="TxType"
                value="#{checkoutBean.sagepayMessage.transactionType}" /> <input
                type="hidden" name="Vendor"
                value="#{checkoutBean.sagepayMessage.vendor}" /> <input
                type="hidden" name="Crypt" class="crypt"
                value="#{checkoutBean.sagepayMessage.crypt}" /> <input
                type="submit" 
                value="Proceed to Checkout" />

        </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to submit a hidden JSF ajax form which in turn renders a script which submits the payment form.

```html
<form action="#{checkoutBean.sagepayURL}" method="post"
    id="SagePayForm" name="SagePayForm">
    ...
    <input type="button" value="Proceed to Checkout" 
        onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenForm:link').click()" />
</form>

<h:form id="hiddenForm" style="display:none">
    <h:commandLink id="link" action="#{checkoutBean.preprocess}">
        <f:ajax render="@form" />
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:outputScript rendered="#{checkoutBean.preprocessed}">
        document.getElementById("SagePayForm").submit();
    </h:outputScript>
</h:form>
```

with

```
private boolean preprocessed; // +getter

public void preprocess() {
    // ...

    preprocessed = true;
}
```

---

Based on your question history, you seem to be using [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), in that case you can also simplify it using [`<o:commandScript>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript) as follows:

```html
<form action="#{checkoutBean.sagepayURL}" method="post"
    id="SagePayForm" name="SagePayForm">
    ...
    <input type="button" value="Proceed to Checkout" onclick="preprocess()" />
</form>

<h:form>
    <o:commandScript name="preprocess" action="#{checkoutBean.preprocess}"
        oncomplete="document.getElementById('SagePayForm').submit()" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: This didnt work...I get the following error: httpError: The HTTP Transport returned a 0 status code. This is usually the result of mixing ajax and full requests.

Comment: If you aren't using a "dead" `<input type="button">` as demonstrated in the answer, add `return false;` to end of `onclick` to block button's default action from being invoked.